# How to use cross_val_score with high order linear regression?

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

I know that we can do cross validation in simple linear regression as

```
lnrreg = LinearRegression()
scores = cross_val_score(lnrreg, X, Y, cv=4, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

But how do we do `cross_val_score()` on linear regression of higher order?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the right solution?

```
lnrreg = LinearRegression()
Xd = PolynomialFeatures(3).fit_transform(X)
scores = cross_val_score(lnrreg, Xd, Y, cv=4, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```